# Not able to get text of alert popup and getting exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, ui-automation

Trying to get text of alert but getting exception Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open looks like it is a modal box please check code for more detail on this.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submit_formset")).click();
Alert alt = driver.switchTo().alert()                                   
String without_data = alt.getText();
System.out.println("alert message when no data is entered:- "+without_data);
```

Check url of image for more details about alert : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk7Ox.png

Html code for current pop-up window is given below let me know for more clarification on this:

```
<body>
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-PF9P8P9" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<section class="main-section">
<footer class="main-footer noprint">
<script src="/static/newdesign/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js">
<script src="/static/newdesign/js/app.js">
<script src="/static/js/tables/responsive-tables.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="modal_message" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal="">
<script src="/static/slick/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script id="" type="text/javascript">
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1157897200940118&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"></noscript>
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front loadingDialog ui-draggable" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-describedby="loadingDialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
<div class="reveal-modal-bg" style="display: block;"></div>
<div id="formset-modal" class="fixed-size-reveal-modal-vehicle open" data-reveal="" style="display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; top: 50px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-container">
<form data-add="true" method="post" action="/vehicle-check/add-vehicles/">
<input type="hidden" value="4J9zftpcYjBkGa93ZNCbEAClbxXAwhEFZVKsw9cKOb01KrtNbXMQviYEyzl4nT02" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
<input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS">
<input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS">
<input id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS">
<input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1000" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="even_row extra-row">
<td>
<select id="id_form-0-vehicle_type" required="" name="form-0-vehicle_type">
<option selected="" value="">---------</option>
<option value="2">VAN</option>
<option value="1">HGV</option>
<option value="3">LGV</option>
<option value="4">BUS</option>
<option value="5">PSV</option>
<option value="6">CAR</option>
<option value="7">Small Passenger</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input id="id_form-0-registration" type="text" maxlength="10" required="" name="form-0-registration">
</td>
<td class="text-center">
<input id="id_form-0-can_attach_trailer" class="can_attach_trailer-field img-checkbox hidden" type="checkbox" name="form-0-can_attach_trailer" style="display: none;">
<img class="img-checkbox" src="/static/kinesisapp/images/empty-checkbox.png" alt="Checkbox" style="cursor: pointer;">
</td>
<td class="vehicle-groups">
<select id="id_form-0-groups" name="form-0-groups">
</td>
<td class="text-center">
<td class="text-center">
<input id="id_form-0-id" type="hidden" name="form-0-id">
</tr>
<tr class="due-date-fields even_row extra-row">
<tr class="error-messages hidden extra-row">
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="display:block; width: 330px;">
</form>
</div>
<div id="extra-form-fields" class="hidden">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not an Alert. Either it's a modal dialog box or within a frame.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to get text of it .

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant HTML in text format?

Comment: Updated question with HTML of current pop-up window. Here I am clicking on "submit_formset" button without selecting and field.

Comment: As you wanted to get the text from the field near to the field `Vehicle Type` I have searched the `HTML` you have shared and didn't find any node with text as `Vehicle Type` nor with the placeholder text `Please select an item in the list`. Update the question with relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: I have updated html, now you can see vehicle type dropdown with id "id_form-0-vehicle_type".